# Print list item in a custom template

Tags: list, spservices, list-item, printing

I'm using **SharePoint 2010** and in one of my `list` I have information about `clients (name, adress, phone number, ...)` and I need to print each item in a `template` like this:

> The client (name), living in(adress) with the phone number(number)
>   ....

Is is possible to generate some kind of `pdf template` or `Web page` with basic html that pint this information ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom web page and show this information as you wants. You can retrieve the information of the lists in your web page using **CSOM**, **JSOM** or **SharePoint Rest API**

For Rest API you can follow the links

- [SharePoint 2010 REST API JQUery Insert, Update, Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820779/sharepoint-2010-rest-api-jquery-insert-update-delete)
- [CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)
- [SharePoint 2013 and Angularjs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002526/SharePoint-and-Angularjs)
- [SharePoint REST API and AngularJs for 2013, 2016 and Online](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115141/REST-API-and-AngularJs-for-SharePoint-and-Online)